# Anyone can help me with SMA* algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have to apply the SMA* algorithm for the labyrinth problem in Python. I found just this PDF: [pdfSMA](https://userweb.cs.txstate.edu/~ma04/files/CS5346/SMA%20search.pdf), but it didn't help me too much.
I tried to resolve it, but I didn't manage. Any implementation for this algorithm in Python would help me.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and maybe we can start from there.

Comment: This not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The original description of SMA* from the original AIMA book is flawed. If you implement it as described it may not work. The issue is that you need to preserve the ordering of children and be sure to explore unexplored children before re-exploring old children.

Felner introduced the idea of [collapse and restore macros](http://www.bgu.ac.il/~felner/2015/SoCS/Collpase.pdf) which can be very helpful in understanding SMA*. I suggest looking at that paper and then using a similar approach to implement the algorithm.

But, also know that the recent [A*+IDA* algorithm](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/0168.pdf) may be a better approach than SMA*. (Not much help if it is an assignment.)